# Removing NULLs from ResultSet

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I am using MySQL.

I have produced the following result-set using a select with joins etc but I wish to remove the nulls if possible and produce a result similar to the second table.

```
-----------------------------------
|#|IMG_KEY|IMAGE|XX_STYLE|YY_STYLE|
-----------------------------------
|1|   1   |PIX01| <NULL> | STYLEB |
|2|   1   |PIX01| STYLEA | <NULL> |
|3|   2   |PIX02| <NULL> | STYLEB |
|4|   2   |PIX02| STYLEA | <NULL> |
|5|   3   |PIX03| <NULL> | STYLEB |
|6|   3   |PIX03| STYLEA | <NULL> |
-----------------------------------
```

NOTE: `XX_STYLE` & `YY_STYLE` are calculated columns.

```
-----------------------------------
|#|IMG_KEY|IMAGE|XX_STYLE|YY_STYLE|
-----------------------------------
|1|   1   |PIX01| STYLEA | STYLEB |
|2|   2   |PIX02| STYLEA | STYLEB |
|3|   3   |PIX03| STYLEA | STYLEB |
-----------------------------------
```

Is it possible to do this using some combination of the `GROUP BY` and/or `HAVING` etc keywords. I've tried `COALESCE` but to no avail.

Comment: Well it would help to show the query.

Comment: What is the datatype of xx_style and yy_style?

Comment: what server are you using?

Comment: `XX_STYLE` & `YY_STYLE` are calculated columns doesn't makes any sense if you don't show any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, IMG_KEY, IMAGE
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(XX_STYLE) XX_STYLE
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(YY_STYLE) YY_STYLE
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY IMG_KEY, IMAGE
```

Result:

```
| ID | IMG_KEY | IMAGE | XX_STYLE | YY_STYLE |
----------------------------------------------
|  1 |       1 | PIX01 |   STYLEA |   STYLEB |
|  3 |       2 | PIX02 |   STYLEA |   STYLEB |
|  5 |       3 | PIX03 |   STYLEA |   STYLEB |
```

To get row numbers starting from 1 try this:

```
SELECT @Row:=@Row+1 AS ID, IMG_KEY, IMAGE
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(XX_STYLE) XX_STYLE
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(YY_STYLE) YY_STYLE
  FROM MyTable
     , (SELECT @Row:=0) r
GROUP BY IMG_KEY, IMAGE
```

Result:

```
| ID | IMG_KEY | IMAGE | XX_STYLE | YY_STYLE |
----------------------------------------------
|  1 |       1 | PIX01 |   STYLEA |   STYLEB |
|  2 |       2 | PIX02 |   STYLEA |   STYLEB |
|  3 |       3 | PIX03 |   STYLEA |   STYLEB |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a5ef/5)

Comment: The data type of xx_style and yy_style are Strings.I didn't include the actual query because I hope not to change it if possible and to achieve my goal by using the keywords I supplied.

Comment: The answer supplied by *hims056* has worked so thank you very much. However just one further question, if all the values in the column or column group are nulls does GROUP_CONCAT() return a NULL then? I'm sorry I included this text in my last response but I hit the wrong key and it got lost, I'm a newbie and this is my first question on this forum.

Comment: @user2655360 - Yes. If all all the values in the column or column group are `NULL` it will return `NULL`. See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa66a/1).

Answer (score 0):

remove those 'null' values using query itself. For that add following line in your query

```
where XX_STYLE is not null and YY_STYLE is not null
```

If you provide your query, then i'll give you complete query

Comment: This wont work on the result if you are using group by with an or clause. For example SELECT thingOne FROM `mytable` WHERE category = 'Cat1' or category2 = 'Cat1' AND thingOne is not null group by cylinder;

Answer (score -1):

Try it using

```
group_concat(xx_style,yy_style)
```

Try to validate the null values. you may get errors in future because of those nulls.